# sqlite create statement for composition class

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

This is my first time trying to develop for android and sqlite, so please help me out here.

I have a table:

Practicals:
PracticalID 
StartDate
EndDate,
PracType,
PracTopic

and then I have the subsequent composition table:

Tasks:
PracticalID ,
TaskNo ,
TaskTopic,
Description and,
Outcomes

My tables in android / sqlite database helper classes look as follows:

//Practical

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PRACTICAL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRACTICAL + "(" +
        Practical_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," + Start_Date + " DATE," + End_Date + 
        " DATE," + Practical_Type + " STRING," + Practical_Topic + " STRING" + ");";
```

//Tasks

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TASKS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASKS + 
"(" +
        Practical_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + 
            Task_No + " INTEGER NOT NULL," + 
            " PRIMARY KEY" + "(" + Practical_ID + "," + Task_No + ")," +  
            Task_Topic +  " STRING," + Task_Description + " STRING," +
        Task_Outcome + " )" + "REFERENCES" + TABLE_PRACTICAL + 
            "(" Practical_ID + "));";
```

My question is whether I have done this correctly or if the PracticalID in Table_tasks should rather be a foreign key? Don't want to get halfway through coding I've made a horrible mistake setting things up.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is not correct; column constraints must come directly after the column, and table constraints must come after all the columns.
Furthermore, to get text affinity, the datatype must contain CHAR or TEXT:

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks(
    Practical_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Practicals(PracticalID),
    TaskNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Task_Topic TEXT,
    Description TEXT,
    Outcomes,
    PRIMARY KEY (PracticalID, TaskNo)
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Going to try it out later. Just a quick additional question regarding table relations - if I had an associative class between two many-to-many classes would they have the same structure?
If the tasks class was an associative class:
    'Practical_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Practicals(PracticalID),
    ModuleCode INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Module (ModuleCode),
    PRIMARY KEY (PracticalID, ModuleCode)'?
Different sites say that both the primary keys for the tables are foreign keys for the associative class while others say they are both the foreign key and primary key.

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.